# Is perl-Net-IP package same as Net-IP package?

Tags: embedded, libraries

I am trying to port a software on aarch64 Linux. One of the requirements of the software is perl-Net-IP library package. When I try to search for the source code of perl-Net-IP package, I get Net-IP package. Are they both same?

Comment: Which distribution are you using?

Comment: I am using Linux given for NXP ls2088 board.

Comment: What package manager is your distribution using? (e.g. yum, dnf, zypper, pacman, apt....)

Comment: It is not having any package manager. I have to build the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Net::IP` is a Perl distribution, that you can find on [MetaCPAN](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::IP), you have a link in the left toolbar to download it.

When it is packaged by some Linux distribution, the name of the distribution package can be `perl-Net-IP` or `libperl-net-ip` or other variations. Hence it depends on the Linux distribution you are using the find the appropriate system package for a given Perl distribution. And you can see documentation refering you to it, based on the target system for the documentation you are reading.

In short, if you just need the Perl module as a dependency and are doing everything by hand, just grab the archive file on MetaCPAN and install it normally.

If not, you will need to provide more context.